# Shell script to delete znodes(Zookeeper)

Tags: sh, apache-zookeeper

i am trying to create a shell script which will delete my znodes. Here is the command:

```
echo "ls /" | zookeeper-client
echo "rmr /collections" | zookeeper-client
```

There are many such nodes i want to delete. Whenever i execute the above commands, sometimes it successfully delete the collections node and sometime it throws error. The reason i found is whenever we run "zookeeper-client" through a shell script, it takes time for the zookeeper shell to come up. 
Is there any way i can delete such nodes ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How long it takes for the shell to come up should be irrelevant -- if it's reading from stdin before it's ready to read from stdin, that's a bug, and should be filed against the zookeeper-client maintainers.

Comment: That said -- could you clarify exactly what the zookeeper-client tool you're referring to is, so I could try to find and refer to its source?

Comment: If this is based on `cli_st` (or `cli_mt`)... short form: They're awful, don't use them. Anything that doesn't wait for a pending async response before shutting down because it has no more requests isn't worth your time to hack around.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete with this
zookeeper-client rmr

e.g zookeeper-client rmr /test

Answer (score 0):

The amount of hackery here is horrendous -- I'm having trouble retaining any self-respect after writing the below.

Please, **please** use a different language rather than adopting the below collection of awful hacks.

```
IFS=$'\n ' read -r -d '' -a names \
  < <(./cli_st 127.0.0.1:2181 < <(sleep 1; echo 'ls /'; sleep 1) 2>&1 | grep '^[[:space:]]')
./cli_st 127.0.0.1:2181 < <(sleep 1; printf 'rmr %s\n' "${names[@]}"; sleep 1; )
```

`cli_st`, here, is the command-line client included in the Zookeeper codebase's C-language bits.